# How to send a data from scala to a particular div tag in Html page

Tags: javascript, html, scala

I have a `List[List[String]]` in my Scala side which I have to send to a div tag of a particular HTML page.

```
    <div class="pagecolumn" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
         <button class="collapsible">Data Info</button>

        <div id="resultDiv" >
          
        </div>
    </div>
   
     
def getResultantValues(modelObject: String, keyName: String):Unit = {
var result = modelObject.replaceAll("\\[","").split("]")
var resultList : mutable.MutableList[mutable.MutableList[String]]= null
for (i<-0 until result.length) {
  resultList += result(i).split(",")
}}`
```

I have to send `ResultList` to the `resultDiv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing details it's quite hard to understand exactly why you need to process the `modelObject` like that or what is the point of `keyName` in your code, but assuming you have `ResultList` of type `List[List[String]]`, and you just need a way to send `resultList` to `resultDiv`, here's how you can do that in Scala:

```
object Something extends App {

  def getResultantValues(modelObject: String): String = {
    val rawSentences: List[String] =
      modelObject
        .replaceAll("makes no sense", "is nonsense")
        .split("\\.")
        .toList
    val resultList: List[List[String]] =
      for (word <- rawSentences) yield word.strip.split(",").toList
    resultList.flatten.mkString("\"", ".", "\"")
  }

  val resultDiv = getResultantValues(
    "This sentence makes no sense. This sentence makes no sense too."
  )

  val htmlString =
    s"""
       |<div class="pagecolumn" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
       |    <button class="collapsible">Data Info</button>
       |
       |    <div id=$resultDiv >
       |          
       |    </div>
       |</div>
       |""".stripMargin

  println(htmlString)
}
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="pagecolumn" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <button class="collapsible">Data Info</button>

    <div id="This sentence is nonsense.This sentence is nonsense too" >
          
    </div>
</div>
```